# Springboot, removed error attributes are available in another media type

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to remove some error attributes from error response in springboot since they could leak sensitive information.

```
 @Component
 public class MyCustomErrorAttributes extends DefaultErrorAttributes {

      @Override
      public Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(WebRequest webRequest, ErrorAttributeOptions options) {

           Map<String, Object> errorAttributes = super.getErrorAttributes(webRequest, options);
           errorAttributes.put("locale", webRequest.getLocale().toString());
           errorAttributes.remove("message");
           errorAttributes.remove("status");
    
           return errorAttributes;
      }
  }
```

This is working when I send a request containing Accept header `application/json`. But when I send `text/html`, I am able to see `message` and `status` attributes in the response. This is leaking the information and looks like someone can try to get extra information from my application.

Here is the response, you can see that the `message` (`<p><b>Message</b>`) attribute exists even if I removed it in `getErrorAttributes` method.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error</h1>
      <hr class="line" />
      <p><b>Type</b> Exception Report</p>
      <p><b>Message</b> Request processing failed: java.lang.NullPointerException: hellow</p>
      <p><b>Description</b> The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
      </p>
      <p><b>Exception</b></p>
      <pre>jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Request processing failed: java.lang.NullPointerException: hellow
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
</pre>
      <p><b>Root Cause</b></p>
      <pre>java.lang.NullPointerException: hellow
    com.example.demo.apiControllers.errorHandling.ExceptionHandlingDenemeController4.errorDeneme(ExceptionHandlingDenemeController4.java:26)
    java.base&#47;jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
</pre>
      <p><b>Note</b> The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.</p>
      <hr class="line" />
      <h3>Apache Tomcat/10.1.1</h3>
   </body>
</html>
```

[text/html media response ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjryE.png)

And you can see that `message` and `status` attributes does not exist in `application/json` response:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1684710265831,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "trace": "java.lang.NullPointerException: hellow\n\tat com.example.demo.apiControllers.errorHandling.ExceptionHandlingDenemeController4.errorDeneme(ExceptionHandlingDenemeController4.java:26)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1080)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1003)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:895)\n\tat jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:705)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:880)\n\tat jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)\n",
    "path": "/4/error_deneme/20",
    "locale": "en_US"
}
```

`locale` attribute I added also does not exist in `text/html` response

EDIT:

It looks like `getErrorAttributes` does not effect response when `text/html` media type is requested

What is going on here? Can you help please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because those attributes are only used for non HTML responses, there is a default HTML page dispaying the default available parameters. If you need additional ones you will need a custom page. However I do not see how `message` and `status` can leak information, the stacktrace however can (and it is configurable if that should be displayed or not).

Comment: Thanks for the response, ```message``` can contain internal info about the application, I cannot guarantee for that, it would be great if the ```message``` attribute also removed from html response too since I am telling spring boot to remove it right...

Comment: No you aren't, as stated the errorattributes aren't used for HTML only for non HTML responses (JSON, XML, plain text).